# Jquery cant traverse elements

Tags: jquery, tree-traversal, jquery-traversing

I am trying to select .singleAnswer but it's not working.

JQUERY:

```
 $(".answerContainer").on("click", ".editAnswer", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
answer = $(this).parent('.answerBar').closest('.singleAnswer'); //this variable doenst work
```

HTML:

```
<div class='answerContainer'>
<p name='singleAnswer' class='singleAnswer'>$answer[$f]</p>
<input type='hidden' value='$answerid[$f]' class='answer_id' />
<p class='ratingBox'> $answerrating[$f]</p>
<div class='answerBar'>
<a href='#' class='upVote vote'>Upvote</a> &middot; <a href='#' class='downVote vote'>Downvote</a>  &middot; 
<a class='answerTime'> $difference $periods[$j] ago</a>
 &middot; <a href='#' style='color: orange;' class='editAnswer'><b>Edit</b></a></div>
```

Comment: assuming `.answerContainer` is the parent of  `singleAnswer`?

Comment: @Loktar yes, edited original question

Comment: Three out of your last four questions are variations on not being able to traverse the tree.  It would really help to read up on the [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) and the [jQuery traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches *up* through the DOM, where you seem to be looking for a sibling of the `.answerBar` element, or, really, a child of the `.answerContainer` element.

Try this:

```
answer = $(this).closest('.answerContainer').find('.singleAnswer');
```

This means go up through the DOM from `this` to the nearest `.answerContainer` element, then from there find descendent(s) with class `.singleAnswer`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for siblings not closest that would start the search up from the current element.

```
answer = $(this).parent('.answerBar').siblings('.singleAnswer');
```